# R apply with custom functions

Tags: r

I'm having trouble applying a custom function in R.  The basic setup is I have a bunch of points, I want to drop a grid over top and get the max z value from each cell.

The code I'm trying is below.  The results I'm looking for would return myGrid$z=c(5,10,na).  The na could be a different value as well as long as I could filter it out later.  I'm getting an error at the apply stage

I believe there is an error in how I'm using apply, but I just haven't been able to get my head wrapped around apply.

thanks,
Gordon

```
myPoints<-data.frame(x=c(0.7,0.9,2),y=c(0.5,0.7,3), z=c(5,3,10))
myGrid<-data.frame(x=c(0.5,2,4),y=c(0.5,3,10))
grid_spacing = 1

get_max_z<-function(x,y) {
    z<-max(myPoints$z[myPoints$x > (x-grid_spacing/2)
        & myPoints$x <= (x+grid_spacing/2)
        & myPoints$y > (y-grid_spacing/2)
        & myPoints$y <= (y+grid_spacing/2)])
            return(z)
}

myGrid$z<-apply(myGrid,1,get_max_z(x,y),x=myGrid$x,y=myGrid$y)
```

Edited to include the return(z) line I left out. added $y to line of custom function above return.

Comment: Your function takes two arguments, you should use `mapply` instead.

Comment: Also your function `get_max_z` does not have a return value!

Comment: Whith `mapply`, use `mapply(get_max_z, myGrid$x,myGrid$y)`. However, `get_max_z(0.5, 0.5)` returns NA for me and not `5`.

Comment: Thanks for the catch, I had rewritten it and forgotten the return(z), I've never used mapply before thanks for the example

Comment: Yeah I get na for both of the first two points, there is another error in the code, I left out a variable name on the last if statement, corrected and it seems to work well

Comment: You might be able to save a lot of pain by using functions in the package `spatstat` or possibly `Rgeos`, both of which let you create objects containing sets of points and then processing those objects in various ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I would recommend you to always boil down a question to its core instead of just posting code. But I think I know what your problem is:

```
> df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(2,1,5))

> f <- function(x,y) {x+y}

> apply(df,1,function(d)f(d["x"],d["y"]))
[1] 3 3 8
```

`apply(df,1,.)` will traverse `df` row wise and hand the current row as an argument to the provided function. This row is a vector and passed into the anonymous function via the only available argument `d`. Now you can access the elements of the vector and hand them further down to your custom function f taking two parameters.

I think if you get this small piece of code then you know how to adjust in your case.

**UPDATE:**

Essentially you make two mistakes:

1. you hand a function call instead of a function to apply.

   function call: `get_max_z(x,y)`

   function:      `function(x,y)get_max_z(x,y)`
2. you misinterpreted the meaning of "..." in the manual to apply as the way to hand over the arguments. But actually this is just the way to pass additional arguments independent of the traversed data object.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I did simplify the code down before posting, although I could have simplified it more I wasn't sure if I was causing errors with the other dataframes in the custom function and I didn't want to leave out any information that could have been causing an error that was unknown to me.

Comment: I just saw that your code was copy-past-run-ready - I think I am pointing you in the right direction.