# Create new column through apply with custom, multi-argument function

Tags: r

I apologize if this question has been asked before (I know there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079182/r-apply-with-custom-functions)), but I have been struggling with this for hours now and cannot find a solution.

Here is a sample of my data frames:

```
mydf1 <- structure(list(r_id = c(574111L, 291615L, 328543L),
  a_name = c("Daft Punk", "Daft Punk", "Daft Punk"),
  r_title = c("Discovery", "TRON: Legacy", "Random Access Memories")),
  .Names = c("r_id", "a_name", "r_title"),
  row.names = c(NA, 3L),
  class = "data.frame")

mydf2 <- structure(list(date_y = c(2015, 2015, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014),
  date_m = c(3, 3, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4),
  date_d = c(28, 21, 7, 31, 24, 17, 17, 10, 3, 26),
  a_name = c("Daft Punk", "Daft Punk", "Daft Punk", "Daft Punk", "Daft Punk", "Daft Punk", "Daft Punk", "Daft Punk", "Daft Punk", "Daft Punk"),
  r_title = c("Discovery", "Discovery", "Random Access Memories", "Random Access Memories", "Random Access Memories", "Random Access Memories", "Discovery", "Random Access Memories", "Random Access Memories", "Random Access Memories"),
  b_rank = c(110, 117, 114, 104, 95, 64, 99, 51, 63, 45),
  l_rank = c(4.52178857704904, 4.44265125649032, 4.47733681447821, 4.58496747867057, 4.67282883446191, 4.92725368515721, 4.63472898822964, 5.01727983681492, 4.93447393313069, 5.05624580534831)),
  .Names = c("date_y", "date_m", "date_d", "a_name", "r_title", "b_rank", "l_rank"),
  row.names = c(NA, -10L),
  class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to add a column to `mydf1`, containing the value returned by the following function:

```
myfunction1 <- function(this_a, this_r){
tot_w <- subset(mydf2, a_name == this_a & r_title == this_r)
return(sum(tot_w$l_rank, na.rm = TRUE))}
```

Being new to R and still used to working with loops in VBA, the idea in my mind is that the function takes the value of `a_name` and `r_title` in `mydf1` as arguments, goes to `mydf2` and subsets the matching rows, if any, then sums the values in `l_rank`. The result should be:

```
mydf3 <- structure(list(r_id = c(574111L, 291615L, 328543L),
  a_name = c("Daft Punk", "Daft Punk", "Daft Punk"),
  r_title = c("Discovery", "TRON: Legacy", "Random Access Memories"),
  l_rank = c("13.59917", "0.000000", "33.67039")),
  .Names = c("r_id", "a_name", "r_title", "l_rank"),
  row.names = c(NA, 3L),
  class = "data.frame")
```

One solution is as follows:

```
mydf3 <- mydf1 %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(l_rank = myfunction1(a_name, r_title))
```

This seems to work, but given that I have to run this on a large number of rows, I suspect it is too slow. Looking at the answer to the question linked above, I have tried using `apply` as follows:

```
mydf3 <- mydf1
mydf3$l_rank <- apply(mydf1, 1,
  function(x, y) myfunction1(mydf1["a_name"], mydf1["r_title"]))
```

But this does not produce the intended result. I have also tried to use `data.table` like this:

```
mydf3 <- data.table(mydf1)
mydf3[, l_rank := myfunction1(mydf3$a_name, mydf3$r_title)]
```

Also to no avail. I would be very grateful if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong because this is giving me a headache.

**EDIT**
Note that rows in `mydf1` can be duplicates.

Comment: Thank you akrun. Would you be so kind to rewrite the function using this method?

Comment: Regarding the recent deleted answer, it is a dupe but it can be helpful to others too.  Also, your question was finding the quickest optimized code.  I was going to update it with a more quicker one, then I found it to be deleted.

Comment: I undeleted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to continue `dplyr` you can use the following:

```
sumdf <- mydf2 %>% group_by(a_name, r_title) %>% 
  summarise(l_rank=sum(l_rank, na.rm=TRUE))

mydf1 %>% merge(sumdf, by=c('a_name','r_title'), all.x=TRUE)
```

I do not use the function but use aggregation with `dplyr::summarise`

Or in one pipe as mentioned in the comments:

```
mydf2 %>% group_by(a_name, r_title) %>% 
  summarise(l_rank=sum(l_rank, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
  right_join(mydf1, by = c('a_name','r_title'))
```

Comment: If you're going `dplyr`, might as well use `left_join`. Or continue the first pipe into a `right_join`.

Comment: Works. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you @Axeman I was not aware that this feature (`*_join` on multiple columns) was added to `dplyr` as it was previously (before v0.3) not possible.

Comment: @Wietze314 That's a long time ago!

Comment: @Axeman I guess I have not noticed. Working with `merge` did not give me any issues so far.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table` join after converting the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT`).

```
library(data.table)
mydf1[, l_rank := setDT(mydf2)[mydf1, .(l_rank=sum(l_rank)),
          on = .(a_name, r_title), by = .EACHI]$l_rank]
#     r_id    a_name                r_title   l_rank
#1: 574111 Daft Punk              Discovery 13.59917
#2: 291615 Daft Punk           TRON: Legacy       NA
#3: 328543 Daft Punk Random Access Memories 33.67039
```

Comment: I tried this with the full data. It is very efficient and seems to work as far as the operation is concerned, but it ends up creating a data frame that has more rows than the initial data frame (`mydf1` in the example above). Why is this?

Comment: @Michele Do you have duplicate 'a_name', 'r_title' in 'mydf1' (in your example, it was not the case.

Comment: Yes, they can differ by the value of some other column. Sorry for not pointing it out.

Comment: @Michele  My solution is based on the example you showed

Comment: @Michele  With duplicate elements, you can try the modified `data.table` solution